# List C functions using man

Tags: c, manpage

You can use man to view information about specific c functions, such as `man strcmp`. Is it possible to list all functions in a header or even just search for functions such as:

```
man string.h
```

or

```
man str*
```

Comment: Did you try `man man`?

Comment: yep, on mac its not so helpful (though I'm asking for linux, I don't currently have access to a linux machine)

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had tried this before asking:

You can just do `man string` or `man stdio` to get a list of functions in each header

Comment: **note:** this is somewhat distribution dependent depending on how they alias `man` using either `apropos` or `whatis`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along the lines of

```
apropos str | grep ^str
```